# How do I make characters in C using the ncurses.h library "blink"

Tags: c, ubuntu, ncurses

Before I make one of these posts, I look around at around 5-10 other forums to see if my question has been answered.

There are a lot of websites that explain that my compiler doesn't have blinking enabled, and that I just need to download the package to enable it, or something to that affect

However, of all the ones that I have seen, none of them go into detail about where and how to acquire the package I need to allow blinking, or if they do then it isn't with my compiler.

So if someone could assist me, how do I enable blinking on Ubuntu with a function such as

```
attron(A_BLINK);
```

I'm aware that similarly phrased questions will get down-votes. I do not care, I just want to know how to fix my problem.

Any feedback would be really appreciated

-Edit

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
  char text[] = "Please Blink";
  size_t len = strlen(text);
  int i, row, col;
  initscr();
  getmaxyx(stdscr, row,col);
  keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
  noecho();
  curs_set(0);

  move((row / 2), (col / 2) - (len / 2));

  attron(A_BLINK);
  for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    printw("%c", text[i]);
  }

  refresh();
  getch();

  attroff(A_BLINK);

  endwin();

  return 0;
}
```

-Ryan

Comment: Edit your question and do the following: 1) remove the first 3 paragraphs which have nothing to do with the question and 2) add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I assume you've seen this? [attron(A_BLINK) using Ncurses does nothing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151673/attrona-blink-using-ncurses-does-nothing)

Comment: @FiddlingBits I did. Maybe I just don't understand that post, but it didn't help me

Comment: @SeanBright The code I provided is about all that you should need. That code there should allow any print statement that follows to blink, but to my understanding the compiler I am using doesn't have blinking installed.

Comment: @SeanBright I'm not trying to be an ass, I just don't know what else is needed. I'd love any help, but I don't really know what extra you need.

Comment: int main(void)
{
 char text[] = "Please Blink";
 size_t len = strlen(text);
 int i, row, col;
 initscr();
 getmaxyx(stdscr, row,col);
 keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
 noecho();
 curs_set(0);

 move((row / 2), (col / 2) - (len / 2));

 attron(A_BLINK);
 for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
 {
  printw("%c", text[i]);
 }


 refresh();
 getch();

 attroff(A_BLINK);
 
 endwin();

 return 0;
}         //   @SeanBright Let me know if that's how you do it, because I've never 
          //made a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @SeanBright Ah ok. Let me know if that's good

Comment: Works fine for me (after including `string.h`) on Ubuntu 19.10, so it most likely has something to do with your `TERM` environment variable or the terminal emulator you are using as @FiddlingBits pointed out.

Comment: @SeanBright yea I forgot to include string.h, but I still don't understand how to fix the problem. Is it when I am compiling the code I add something to the command line? Is it something I have to download into ubuntu directly? Is it something else entirely? I don't understand the terminology "TERM"

Comment: `TERM` is an environment variable (type `echo $TERM` and hit enter at your Ubuntu command prompt). The curses library uses that value to determine what capabilities your terminal emulator supports.

Comment: @SeanBright Alright so I gave that a try, and it gave me back "xterm-256color" and nothing else. I assume to get my program to work, I need another "xterm" to be present

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ncurses attribute A\_DIM has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419186/ncurses-attribute-a-dim-has-no-effect).  The particular attribute doesn't matter: some terminals do **not** support blinking text.

Answer (score 0):

[ansi escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

as an example of usage:

from the terminal type:

```
echo -e "\x1b[5;32;43m"
```

this results in a blinking green foreground over a yellow background

then type:

```
echo "test"
```

to display the word test as green letters over a yellow background

then, if the screen has not returned to normal operation, type:

```
echo -e "\1b[0m"
```

to reset the screen to normal

Note: the same ansi escape sequences can be output using the `printf()` function via:

```
printf( "%s\n", "\x1b[5;32;43m" );
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Blinking is a property of your terminal emulator. If your terminal does not support it, it won't happen.

FWIW, a plain `xterm` window does support blinking for me.

However, if you want the text to blink, you can manually make it happen by periodically overwriting the text with blanks. Something along the lines of:

```
int toggle = 0;
halfdelay(5);

do {
    toggle = !toggle;
    move((row / 2), (col / 2) - (len / 2));
    printw("%*.*s", len, len, toggle ? text : "");
    refresh();
} while (getch() == ERR);

nocbreak();
```

The `halfdelay()` call will cause `getch()` to return after 5/10<sup>ths</sup> of a second. If no key was hit within that time, `ERR` is returned. The `nocbreak()` call will disable `halfdelay()`.